# Css not working for Dockerized VueJs Project

Tags: css, vue.js, nginx

I've created a VueJs project and deployed it to AWS. I've dockerized the project according to the [document (Real-World Example section)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app.html). I've just added a line for copying my nginx conf file, like this:

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY confs/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Then I've realized that my css does not working when I've checked the page url. I also have a conf file like this:

```
events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}

http {

  server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index  index.html index.htm;
      include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

  }
}
```

I know that there is numerous answers for nginx css problems and I've tried a bunch of those, still could not get any solutions.

These are a couple of solutions that I've tried already.

[Nginx fails to load css files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075304/nginx-fails-to-load-css-files)

[Nginx failing to load CSS and JS files (MIME type error)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573489/nginx-failing-to-load-css-and-js-files-mime-type-error)

[Firebase "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49160391/firebase-resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text)

Answer (score 0):

you must set "include /etc/nginx/mime.types" in the http section

```
http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  server {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your Nginx is configured to serve files from

```
/usr/share/nginx/html;
```

it must also serve your css files

add these lines

```
location /css/ {
   alias /usr/share/nginx/html/css/;
}
```

assume that your css files are located in the folder called `css`
inside the folder`/usr/share/nginx/html`